# JsonArray parsing

Tags: android, json

Please help me for parsing this json Array response.
This is response json response.
The problem is split "tag_id",tag_name

```
{
    "tag": "allcompanyprofiles",
    "success": 1,
    "error": 0,
    "searchresult": [{
            "id": "146",

            "name": "SJB Bookkeeping and Accounting",
            "slug": "sjb-bookkeeping-and-accounting",
            "contact_name": "Bernard Newman",
            "category_id": "7",
            "description": "hello",
            "lon": "-79.787231600000",
            "lat": "43.360581400000",
            "address": "3425 Harvester unit 206",
            "city": "Burlington",
            "state": "Ontario",
            "postcode": "L7N 3M7",
            "country": "CA",
            "phone": "905-335-0081",
            "email": "sjb@sjbbookkeeping.com",
            "time_frame": "Morning,Afternoon,All Day",
            "onsite_requirements": "WHIMIS TRAINING",
            "position": "Accounting, Administration",
            "oyap": "No",
            "shsm": "Yes",
            "summer": "Yes",
            "virtual": "No",
            "website": "sjbbookkeeping.com\/",
            "user_id": "1",
            "title": "Finance\/Accounting",
            "dlc_slug": "financeaccounting",
            "tag_id": ["47", "79"],
            "tag_name": ["administration", "accounting"]
        }, {
            "id": "145",

            "name": "Length Hair Bar",
            "slug": "length-hair-bar",
            "contact_name": "Amalea",
            "category_id": "29",
            "description": "hello",
            "lon": "-79.394569700000",
            "lat": "43.675291300000",
            "address": "162A Davenport Road",
            "city": "Toronto",
            "state": "Ontario",
            "postcode": "M5R 1J2",
            "country": "CA",
            "phone": "416-823-3755",
            "email": "lengthhairbar@yahoo.com",
            "time_frame": "Morning,Afternoon,All Day",
            "onsite_requirements": "WHIMIS TRAINING",
            "position": "Hair Stylist Assistant, Customer Service",
            "oyap": "Yes",
            "shsm": "Yes",
            "summer": "Yes",
            "virtual": "No",
            "website": "",
            "user_id": "1",
            "title": "Esthetics",
            "dlc_slug": "esthetics",
            "tag_id": ["178", "177", "179"],
            "tag_name": ["stylist", "hair", "esthetics"]
        }

    ]
}
```

This is my android code.

```
                JSONObject jobjsearch=new JSONObject(strjson);

                tag_list=jobjsearch.getString("tag");
                success_list=jobjsearch.getString("success");
                error_list=jobjsearch.getString("error");

                // Total Result Counted
                total_count = jobjsearch.getString("totalcount");

                Log.v("TagSearch",tag_list);
                Log.v("SuccessSearch",success_list);
                Log.v("ErrorSearch",error_list);

                //JsonArray Working

                JSONArray jarr_list =jobjsearch.getJSONArray("searchresult");


                for (int i=0; i<jarr_list.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject obbj=jarr_list.getJSONObject(i);

                    /////////////////////////// Tagsid
                    tagsid_default=obbj.getString("tag_id");
                    arrtagsid_list.add(tagsid_default);

                    String CurrentString = "Fruit: they taste good";
                    String[] separated = CurrentString.split(":");

                    //Tagsname

                    tagsname_default=obbj.getString("tag_name");
                    arrtagsname_list.add(tagsname_default);

                    /////////////////////////////////

                    wesite_default=obbj.getString("website");
                    arrweb_list.add(wesite_default);

                    email_default=obbj.getString("email");

                    name_list = obbj.getString("name");

                    arrname_list.add(name_list);

                    Log.v("Companyname",name_list);

                    // allNames.add(name);

                    address_list = obbj.getString("address");

                    arraddress_list.add(address_list);

                    Log.v("Companyaddress",address_list);

                    city_list = obbj.getString("city");

                    arrcity_list.add(city_list);

                    Log.v("Companycity",city_list);

                    state_list = obbj.getString("state");

                    arrstate_list.add(state_list);

                    Log.v("Companystate",state_list);

                    country_list = obbj.getString("country");

                    arrcountry_list.add(country_list);

                    Log.v("Companycountry",country_list);

                    //categorytitle

                    categoryid_list=obbj.getString("title");

                    arrcategoryid_list.add(categoryid_list);

                    Log.v("category",categoryid_list);

                    //title_list=obbj.getString("title");
                    //arrtitle_list.add(title_list);

                    intro_list=obbj.getString("intro");
                    arrintro_list.add(intro_list);


                    ///categoryid
                    str_categoryid=obbj.getString("category_id");
                    arrcategryid_list.add(str_categoryid);


                    //get id in integer variable

                    //pos=obbj.getInt("id");
                    //arrid_list.add(pos);

                    //get id in string variable

                    str_pos=obbj.getString("id");
                    arrayid_list.add(str_pos);


                    Log.e("DefaultPosition"+pos,"");

                    //setset.setId(obbj.getString("id"));
                    //setset.setName(obbj.getString("name"));

                }
```

Comment: That is an array. Treat them as a `JSONArray`

Comment: i want  to get   "tag_id": ["47", "79"], differt 
            "tag_name": ["administration", "accounting"] and administration,accounting different

Comment: @nanoweb: How do you expect to read a ``JSONArray` as a string and split it? See my answer for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are `JSONArray`'s. Treat them as a `JSONArray`.

Change

```
tagsid_default=obbj.getString("tag_id");
arrtagsid_list.add(tagsid_default);
```

to

```
JSONArray tempId = obbj.getJSONArray("tag_id");
for(int i = 0; i< tempId.length(); i++)
{
    arrtagsid_list.add(tempId.get(i).toString());
}
```

**And**

Change

```
tagsname_default=obbj.getString("tag_name");
arrtagsname_list.add(tagsname_default);
```

to

```
JSONArray tempName = obbj.getJSONArray("tag_name");
for(int i = 0; i< tempName.length(); i++)
{
    arrtagsname_list.add(tempName.get(i).toString());
}
```

**Note:** I strongly feel you should read about `JSON` fist before trying to parse it, so that you don't make mistakes like this. Here are [basics of JSON](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/)